# wp_schedule_single_event schedule with specific date?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to setup scheduling single event cron `wp_schedule_single_event` function, where i checked by passing first parameter as `strtotime('+1 days');` and it setup cron perfectly for **24 hour**s, if i do things like below it setup **12 hours** no matter what?

```
$last_date_of_membership = "19-02-2017"; // d-m-y europe style 
$penalty_day = strtotime($last_date_of_membership."+1 days");
wp_schedule_single_event($penalty_day,'some_hook_name');
```

It just schedule 12 hours not 24 hours, later that i tried with `h:i:s` still the same 12 hours is what scheduled in cron.

I checked the documentation of wordpress where it state use unix timestamp which is gmt https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event

Are there any limitation where we cannot use *strtotime which is converted from date* in scheduling cron? If so please suggest someother alternate to overcome this problem.

> NOTE: I just specified tomorrow date as an example.

Any suggestion would really great?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out the solution for that problem which is time format, pass the hour minutes and seconds as 24 hours format, if it is 12 hours then 1.00 p.m is consider as a.m  and it schedule for 12 hours. Hope it may help to someone to avoid such a issue in future.

Thanks.